# Having trouble with and Excel spreadsheet, in google colab and a column is missing

Tags: pandas

Yes this is homework and no I don't want an answer to the question, but for some reason the column I would like to move using pandas is missing yet I can still see it on my end result. Why is this happening. This is what I have done:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import seaborn as sns

    #read xlsx file

   df = pd.read_excel("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX- 
   1vTd9TqybCunAe9HPPdb5mOW5uFn5m5fXO-mecfsn0TEk10_l8Bz1Kc7k13AFWoyvC1t3A7A27zozfTd/pub? 
   output=xlsx")
   df

   #removes last 2 rows

   df.iloc[0:, 0:21]

   #columns grouped by type float

   df.iloc[0:, [0,2,4,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]]

   #columns grouped by type object

    df.iloc[0:, [1,3,5,6,7]]

#gets dummies and stores them in variables

type_float = df.iloc[0:, [0,2,4,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]]
type_object = df.iloc[0:, [1,3,5,6,7]]
#concatonates the dummies to orignal dataframe
df = pd.concat([type_float, type_object], axis='columns')
df

#rename

df.rename(columns = {'Attrition_Flag':'Target'}, inplace = True)
df

#Replaceing target with 0/1

df['Target'].replace(['Existing Customer', 'Attrited Customer'],[0, 1], inplace=True)
df
'''
```

This is where im having trouble

When I try to move column "target" I cant. Ive tried to pop it, and then move it to the back
and when I try using "`df.iloc[0:, [15]]`" which is its column, it just goes to the next column. Why is this column non-existent? anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly what you need to do but if you want to change the order of columns (make `'Target'` the last column) you can use:

```
all_columns_in_new_order = list(df.columns.drop('Target')) + ['Target']
```

and then:

```
df = df.reindex(all_columns_in_new_order, axis=1)
```